# Prevent a form from closing when its parent closes

Tags: winforms

I am having a small issue with an application I am trying to develop.
I have notifications that popup using some code I found online (ToastForms).  It pops up a little notification window in the bottom right hand side of the screen and then disappears.  Works a treat.

However, my issue is that when I click on the notification window, I want to open another window modally from Form1.  So for example, I have my main form (Form1), then a notification shows a second form (Form2) and when I click on Form2 it opens a third form (Form3).

This works fine, until Form2 auto closes.  It then closes Form3 automatically.
Is there a way I can open a form from Form2 using Form1 as the parent?  So closing Form2 has no affect on Form3?

I can't hide Form2 because if more notifications come through, it will stack these on top of the hidden forms.  If Form3 is open for a long time, it could mean a lot of hidden notification forms.

**Update**

Ok, so my code to open a new notification looks like this:

```
If Notifications.Exists(Function(p) p.Id = tempDT.Rows(x)("id").ToString) = False Then
                    Notifications.Add(New Notification() With {.Id = tempDT.Rows(x)("id").ToString, .Description = "Call ID #" & tempDT.Rows(x)("id").ToString & " has now become overdue", .Read = False, .Type = "Overdue"})
                    Dim slice As New ToastForm(10000, "Call ID #" & tempDT.Rows(x)("id").ToString & " has now become overdue")
                    slice.Height = 100
                    slice.Show()
                End If
```

Then, under the ToastForm I have a click event on the label control, so when the user clicks on the window (with a fullsize docked label control), it opens my notifications form against the main form (frmNewDashboard):

```
Private Sub messageLabel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles messageLabel.Click
    Dim frm As New frmShowNotifications
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
            frm.Location = New Point(frmNewDashboard.Location.X + 1570, frmNewDashboard.Location.Y + 90)
            frm.ShowDialog()
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
End Sub
```

Lastly, the ToastForm has a timer event.  When the timer reaches its length, it calls the close event which closes both the ToastForm and the frmNotifications form:

```
Private Sub lifeTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles lifeTimer.Tick
    'The form's lifetime has expired.
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: you probably better show piece of code, that part you use to open Form2 and Form3 at least

Comment: Sorry chouaib - please see updated thread